# Populate method is not populating data when associated to another model

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have associated my User schema model with Post schema model, and I'm trying to populate **post** model data into **user** model, but I always get `null` value.
I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. Please help. thanks in advance!

```
userSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    email: String,
    posts: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Post"
    }]
});

postSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    content: String
});
```

and here is my query to achieve the above-said result (assume that post and user data is created properly):

```
User.find({name: 'Vignesh'}).populate("posts").exec(function(err, post){
    if(!err){
        console.log("..........populated posts of User........");
        console.log(post);
    } else {
        console.log(err);
    }

});
```

Comment: This is how I created User data:

`User.create({name: 'Vignesh',email: 'vignesh@me.in'}, function(err, post){
    if(!err){
        console.log(post);
    } else {
        console.log(err);
    }
    
});`

Comment: Have you tried `.populate({path:"posts"})` ?

Comment: Yes, I did try it, but no luck :(

Comment: what is your mongodb and mongoose version?